# Stored Procedure gives an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a MSSQL stored procedure as below:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetDataFromTable]
(
@rowval varchar(50),
@tablename varchar(50),
@oby varchar(50)
)
as
begin
EXEC('Select top (' + @rowval + ') * from '+@tablename+ 'ORDER BY '+@oby+' DESC')
end
```

On execution, it gives following error:
    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BY'.
I tried following also, still the same error:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetDataFromTable]
(
@rowval varchar(50),
@tablename varchar(50),
@oby varchar(50)
)
as
begin
EXEC('Select top (' + @rowval + ') * from '+@tablename+ 'ORDER BY sno DESC')
end
```

Note: @rowval represents number of rows to be fetched, @tablename represents name of table, @oby represents column based on which ordering should be done.
Note: I am using ASP.Net with C# at frontend to fire this procedure and using MSSQL 2008 R2 Express Edition at the backend

Answer (score 6):

Give some space *after* `@tablename` and *before* `ORDER`

```sql
Declare @sql varchar(max)=''

SET @sql = 'Select top (' + @rowval + ') * from '+quotename(@tablename)+ ' ORDER BY sno DESC'
                                                                        --^here
EXEC (@sql)
```

Also start using `Print/Select` to debug the `dynamic sql`

To add some security to this dynamic sql I will make the following changes

1. Make the `@rowval` as `INT`
2. Use `QUOTENAME` function in `@tablename` parameter to avoid sql injection
3. Will use `SP_EXECUTESQL` to execute the dynamic query instead of `EXEC`

Here is a correct way to do it

```sql
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)='',@tablename varchar(130), @rowval int 

select @sql  = 'Select top  (@rowval) * from '+quotename(@tablename)+ ' ORDER BY sno DESC'

exec sp_executesql @sql,N'@rowval int',@rowval = @rowval
```

Comment: @ITSagar - We all make mistakes

Comment: Thanks, but where to put quotename and how? I have tried, but got errors

Comment: EXEC('Select top (' + @rowval + ') * from '+quotename(@tablename)+ ' ORDER BY sno DESC')
Error I Get is : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetDataFromTable, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'quotename'.

Comment: @ITSagar - yep we cannot use `function` when putting the string directly in `exec` updated my answer check now.

Comment: I wrote the three statements inside this SP creation code ::: CREATE PROCEDURE GetDataFromTable
AS
BEGIN
<Your code lines here>
END
GO
but i didnt get data when i executed it from asp.net

Comment: @ITSagar - You need to check the data present in table. Also use print statement and copy the printed query and execute it manually to check

Comment: Data is present. Even if I right click and execute procedure, it doesnot expect any parameters and returns 0 as return value.